# Manipulate CSS Psuedo ::After properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a timeline scrubber where I have a marker that is dragged left and right with a ::after element styled on it. I need to be able to set the height of the line depending on how many layers are present, but I don't see how to access the DOM element. I have done some searching and while there have been some solutions by adding  elements to the body, that would quickly become unwieldy and cluttered compared to simply modifying the css directly.

I have a demo here: http://codepen.io/ajhalls/pen/QdgXBQ

for simplicity sake, I simplified it to trying to access the height on dragging the slider left and right. While this uses jQuery, I am certainly fine with any other solutions that use plain JS as well.

```
$(".scrubber-icon").draggable({ 
    axis: 'x',
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        var scrubberValue = ($(".scrubber-icon").position().left-15);
        $(".scrubber-icon").css( "::after", "height", scrubberValue);
       $("#text").html("position:" + scrubberValue);

    }

});
```

Comment: You can't easily modify `::after` pseudo elements using JS. Better to use actual dom nodes in this instance, although I am a little unsure of what you are asking to be honest...

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of modifying the element rather than addRule or some such way? I want to be able to make the red line shorter and longer is the goal not by appending more rules, but modifying the existing one.

Comment: An after element can just be replaced by another node and then you can do what you want. Why the need for the `::after`?

Comment: Because the two are supposed to move together using jQueryUI draggable(), the simplest way was to style the one element, I just can't figure out now how to modify it's height.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish, I checked your codepen and read your question twice but I cannot understand what height you are trying to modify. Why not simple use a node instead of and after and add `pointer-events: none` to it to allow dragging of the parent without interference?

Comment: I am rebuilding something like this: https://github.com/legomushroom/mojs-timeline-editor but I want it to be a super simple widget to fork as opposed to the normal 35,000 lines. Depending on how many layers you add, you may only need the red line to be 100px tall, other times 300px tall. Yes I know I can work around it by adding nodes and so on, but the point is that there SHOULD be a way to directly modify that value and I don't see one. As such, if such a way exists, it would benefit StackOverflow users to acknowledge it and post a solution to modifying a pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo elements are not accessible through javascript directly, they are defined in stylesheets. The way you *could* modify your pseudo elements is by writing your own on-the-fly stylesheet. Now in all fairness, I just quickly mocked this up to see if it would work but I have no idea how taxing on the browser it is when the stylesheet gets reevaluated often.

The script below adds a function called `jsPseudo`. You pass in a `node`, a pseudo type and either a string (that will return the value inside that attribute - if you set it with this function before) or an `object`, where the key is the attribute and the value is, well, the value. It adds one stylesheet to the page that it will rewrite as you make updates.

```js
const jsPseudo = function(){
    var pseudos = {},
        count = 1,
        style = document.createElement('style');
    document.body.appendChild( style );
    return function( node, type, keyValues ){
        var id = node.getAttribute('data-has-pseudo');
        if( !id ){
            id = count++;
            node.setAttribute('data-has-pseudo', count);
        }
        id = `[data-has-pseudo="${count}"]:${type}`;
        pseudos[id] = pseudos[id] || {content:''};
        if( typeof keyValues === 'object' ){
            for( let key in keyValues ){
                pseudos[id][key] = keyValues[key];
            }
            style.textContent = '';
            for( let key in pseudos ){
                style.textContent += `${key}{`
                for( attr in pseudos[key] ){
                    style.textContent += `${attr}:${pseudos[key][attr]};`
                }
                style.textContent += `};`;
            }
            return node;
        } else if( typeof keyValues === 'string' ){
            return pseudos[id][keyValues];
        }
    }
}();

jsPseudo( document.body, 'after', {
    'content':'"Hello world!"'
});

console.log( jsPseudo( document.body, 'after', 'content' ) );
```

As for your specific code, you could now replace this:

```
$(".scrubber-icon").css( "::after", "height", scrubberValue);
```

with this:

```
jsPseudo( this, "after", { height: scrubberValue + 'px'} )
```

And it will update the stylesheet for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I needed to change the first line to `var jsPseudo = function(){`, something in the behavior of it being  a constant didn't work but does as a variable.

Comment: The code is ES6, so it might need compiling depending on what you use :) cheers!